# Take out one record from database to select list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question about take a record to select list.

**It is my database**

```
|Height | Width|
|82     | 450  |
|110    | 450  |
|120    | 450  |
|140    | 600  |
|150    | 700  |
```

**PHP code**

```
 <?php
    function width(){
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("partition");

    $query = "SELECT width FROM width_height where width='450' limit 1;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo("$row[0]");
    mysql_free_result($result);
    }
 ?>
    <p>Width (MM):
    <select name="width" id="width1">
    <option><?php width(); ?></option>
    </select><br>
```

**My expect select list:**

```
Width: |450|
       |600|
       |700|
```

Here, I want to take out 450,600,700 record and display on the select list

It is SQL language problem or PHP...???
**Have a suggestion to me?**

Comment: Please use PDO or mysqli (MySQL Improved Extension) such as mysqli_connect, mysqli_select_db etc. instead of mysql_* functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the unique list of widths, change your query to

```
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT width FROM width_height;";
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try :

```
select width from width_height group by width
```